# How can panels be rearranged / order be changed?

Tags: interface, customization

To avoid the need of scrolling I'd like to move *MHX Layers* between *Transform* and *Grease Pencil*. Once I saw a video tutorial where this was done but I can't remember which one it was.

[image: Change order of panels in N-Toolshelf]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The panel list can be re-arranged by dragging the top-right corner of each panel (the little triangle-like area with three small backslashes), then drop it after moving up or down.

[image]